# python beautifulsoup4 how to get span text in div tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is the html code

```
<div aria-label="RM 6,000 a month" class="salary-snippet"><span>RM 6,000 a month</span></div>
```

I used like this

```
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='job_seen_beacon')
    for item in divs:
        print(item.find('div', class_='salary-snippet'))
```

i got the result a list such as

```
<div aria-label="RM 3,500 to RM 8,000 a month" class="salary-snippet"><span>RM 3,500 - RM 8,000 a month</span></div>
```

if i used

```
print(item.find('div', class_='salary-snippet').text.strip())
```

it will return the error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

so how can i get only the span text? its my first time web **scraping**

Comment: please post your full code, including the url, so we can reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking for.

- First select all the `<div>` tags with class as `salary-snippet` as this is the parent of the `<span>` tag that you are looking for. Use `.find_all()`
- Now Iterate over the all the selected `<div>` tags from above and find the `<span>` from each `<div>`.
- Based on your question, I assume that **All these `<div>` may not have the `<span>` tag**. In that case you can print the text only if the `<div>` contains a `span` tag. See below

```
# Find all the divs
d = soup.find_all('div', class_='salary-snippet')
# Iterating over the <div> tags
for item in d:
    # Find <span> in each item. If not exists x will be None
    x = item.find('span')
    # Check if x is not None and then only print
    if x:
        print(x.text.strip())
```

Here is the complete code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = """<div aria-label="RM 6,000 a month" class="salary-snippet"><span>RM 6,000 a month</span></div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'lxml')

d = soup.find_all('div', class_='salary-snippet')
for item in d:
    x = item.find('span')
    if x:
        print(x.text.strip())
```

```
RM 6,000 a month
```

Comment: thanks, i never thought using find_all will work... i guess even it just have one span text, iterate to get the span text still do the magic

Answer (score 0):

I believe the line should be:

```
print(item.find('div', {'class':'salary-snippet'}).text.strip())
```

Alternatively, if there is only the `span` you can simply use:

```py
item.find("span").text.strip()
```

Considering you used the `.find_all()` method you might want to ensure that every `div` returned from your HTML

```py
soup.find_all('div', class_='job_seen_beacon')
```

contains the element you are looking for as thi could arise if only one element doesn't.

i.e.

```py
divs = soup.find_all('div', class_='job_seen_beacon')
for item in divs:
    try:
        print(item.find('div', {'class':'salary-snippet'}).text.strip())
    except AttributeError:
        print("Item Not available")
```

What this will do is try get the text but if this fails will print the item that failed so you can identify why... perhaps it doesn't have the element you are searching for.

Comment: Thanks for the edit however i would also print the item just for him/her to identify why it doesn't have the attribute but thats just personal debuggin preference